# Showing cart status in my shopping webapp

Tags: python, html, django

I made my first shopping cart, everything works but now i want to make that when cart is empty then his link should have written "cart is empty" but when i will put something to him then his link should have written "cart". I have that code in html for this:

```
<a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/cart/">
    {% if cart == None %}cart is empty{% else %}cart{% endif %}
</a>
```

And now when i am in cart page then his link have written "cart", but when I'm outside cart page then its written"cart is empty", and it doesn't have matter if there are some products in cart or not.

cart.py

```
from decimal import Decimal
from django.conf import settings
from shop.models import Product

class Cart(object):

def __init__(self, request):
    self.session=request.session
    cart=self.session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
    if not cart:
        cart = self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = {}
    self.cart=cart

def add(self, product, quantity=1, ):
    product_id=str(product.id)
    if product_id not in self.cart:
        self.cart[product_id]={'quantity':0,'price':str(product.price) }
        self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] = quantity
    else:
        self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] += quantity

    self.save()

def save(self):
    self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = self.cart
    self.session.modified=True

def remove(self, product):
    product_id=str(product.id)
    if product_id in self.cart:
        del self.cart[product_id]
        self.save()

def __iter__(self):
    product_ids=self.cart.keys()
    products=Product.objects.filter(id__in=product_ids)
    for product in products:
        self.cart[str(product.id)] ['product']=product

    for item in self.cart.values():
        item['price']=Decimal(item['price'])
        item['total_price']= item['price'] * item['quantity']
        yield item

def clear(self):
    del self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID]

def get_total_price(self):
    return sum(Decimal(item['price'])*item['quantity'] for item in   self.cart.values())
```

Comment: You `cart`  is probably only being inserted into the `/cart` page. You need to include your cart in _every_ page. You can do this via a "context process" or middleware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment, you need to insert the `cart` object in *every* page of your app, not just the `/cart/` page. You can do this with a ["context processor"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext):

Create a `context_processors.py` in your `cart` app and add something like the following:

```
from cart import Cart

def cart_processor(request):
    return {
        # You need to be sure that this is returning the cart
        # that is unique for the current user. It looks like you
        # are doing this already in the __init__ method, but just
        # be sure that you don't accidently insert the wrong object
        'cart': Cart(request)
    }
```

Then in your settings, find the `TEMPLATES.context_processors` setting and add the path to your new context processors:

```
TEMPLATES = [
     ...
     OPTIONS = {
         ...
         "context_processors": [
             ...
             "cart.context_processors.cart_processor",
             ...
```

You will now have the `cart` variable available in every template in your app.